# Should only one component own state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three components (all currently owning `state` as they each handle the `state` of their input fields). I was reading that one common component should own the state.

So I have this common component:

```
var UnitConverter= React.createClass({

  render: function(){
     return(
        <div>
            <Temperature/>
            <Length/>
            <Mass/>
        </div>
    )
   }
});
```

And then the `Temperature`, `Length`, and `Mass` components: https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/fvgv5rb2/1/ I am not sure if it is good practice to have so many components all owning `state`. How would I centralize the `state` exactly?

Comment: You can centralize your state using a package like Redux, which is excellent for this exact purpose. The creator of Redux, who is now directly working with React at Facebook, has an excellent set of tutorials at egghead: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: I think this is an overkill to introduce Redux into such small problem

Comment: How so, if you want to get into actual React development you'll need more than `this.setState({})`? Why not learn it now on a small scale project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To centralize the state, you can pass a callback to the component which will then pass the value down to your `UnitConverter`, as following:

```
var UnitConverter= React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { temperature: 0, length: 0, mass: 0 }
  }

  render: function(){
     return(
        <div>
            <Temperature value={this.state.temperature} onChange={this.handleTemperatureChange} />
            <Length value={this.state.length} onChange={this.handleLengthChange} />
            <Mass value={this.state.mass} onChange={this.handleMassChange} />
        </div>
    )
   }

   handleTemperatureChange: function(temperature) {
     this.setState({ temperature: temperature })
   }

   handleLengthChange: function(length) {
     this.setState({ length: length })
   }

   handleMassChange: function(mass) {
     this.setState({ mass: mass })
   }
});
```